# macbook pro hosts file not working correctly

Tags: macbook-pro, hosts

I am trying to set up a production server ahead of the actual dns switch.  I have edited my hosts file on my macbook pro 10.8.2.

I can pull up the index page but none of the style sheets are pulled in and if I click on a link it redirects to the main site.
This is the same behavior on safari and FF

The funny thing is, it works fine in IE.
Is the behavior of a hosts file on on a mac different than from a windows hosts file?
Apparently so. 
Has anyone seen this behavior before and know how to work around it?
thanks

Comment: maybe it is not your host file but your code? path is set 'wrong' but IE does a workaround? What would help is posting your host file here.

Comment: If there were an issue with your hosts file, you wouldn't be able to pull the index page (on the same host). You probably should be looking in another direction to solve your problem.